# Different ways to create ng-grid gridOptions?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

An ng-grid uses gridOptions, which define what data to display. The api only shows simple examples such as

```
$scope.myData = [{name:'test'}];
var gridOption={data:'myData'}
```

It doesn't explain how to set data. If myData is an array of arrays instead

```
$scope.myData = [[{}],[{}]];
var gridOptions={data:'myData[0]'};
```

works and replacing 0 with 1 works. However, I can't seem to use a variable for the index?

I want to do

```
var gridOptions={data:'myData[index]'};
```

why doesn't this work and what are my options?

Comment: what about: `'myData[' + index + ']'` ?

Comment: basically `'myData[index]'` index isn't treated as a variable because its a string so it really think you mean the word, index. My comment above should work.

Comment: thanks friend, I was stuck on this for so long can't believe I didn't think of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `'myData[index]'` isn't treated as a variable. It is seen as a string. What you would have to do is convert it to a string after the var is read like so `'myData[' + index + ']'`